# react 18 typescript types in package.json

Tags: react-18

Im trying to upgrade my react 17 to 18

```
"@types/react": "???????",
"@types/react-dom": "????????",
"react": "^18.0.0",
"react-dom": "^18.0.0",
```

What should I put in `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Create React App to generate a new TypeScript project and take a look at the dependencies, since I was striking out with the recommendation of removing @types/react and @types/react-dom. That was not fun.

I ended up installing these types:

```
"@types/react": "^17.0.43",
"@types/react-dom": "^17.0.14",
```

Then I could use the following to mount my app in index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
....
const container = document.getElementById('root');
// OH BOY, container can be null but createRoot can't handle this...
if (!container) {
   throw "Can't instantiate";
}
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(
   <React.StrictMode>
   <App />
   </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Yes, there is a problem with the current typescript type where it could receive a null, and you have to guard it with an if / throw check... Or do a ts-ignore.

I'm hoping that gets fixed somehow.  But anyway, it's 1AM here and I finally was able to get my app working with React 18 and Typescript using this hack.

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't get this to work until I removed the carrots from the versions of `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom`. It might be due to breaking changes mentioned [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/56210), but I'm not familiar enough to know for sure.

The issue was that it couldn't resolve `react-dom/client`.

Answer (score 0):

At the time I write this, the React 18 types don't appear to be finished yet (see [tweet from maintainer](https://twitter.com/sebsilbermann/status/1508856498071384072)). There are former "@next" versions of React 18 types, but they don't match the React 18 release and probably shouldn't be used. Sit tight and they'll likely be finished/released in the coming days.

Answer (score 0):

while react team working on the new types release, if you want to test it out you can keep the old `"@types/react": "^17.0.40"` and `"@types/react-dom": "^17.0.13"` types version, and inside the `index.tsx` after updating `react` and `react-dom` to version `18.0.0` you need first to import `ReactDOM` from `react-dom/client` and then create the root element from the element `id=root` using `createRoot` and then use `.render` to render the content of the `<App/>` component inside the created root element like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

let root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom`  [are now on v18](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react). Here's how I upgraded:

- uninstall both those packages
- upgrade to react 18
- `yarn install -D @types/react @types/react-dom`, which automatically uses v18 types now. (or `npm install --save-dev ...`)

I'm sure there's a way that doesn't require you to uninstall first via `yarn upgrade`, but that didn't work for me for some reason.